# AngularJs: set/get object into cookies

Tags: angularjs, laravel, object, cookies

I am try to get object which I set into the cookie but it gives me o/p like [Object Object].

Here is code when I SET object into cookie:

```
click: function (event, ui) {
 //other code
 $scope.fields = {name:true, image:true, subname:false, date:true};
 setCookie('title', $scope.fields, 1);
}
```

Here is code to get cookie :

```
var test = getCookie('title');
```

This test console o/p give me **[Object Object]**. I want o/p like :{name:true, image:true, subname:false, date:true}

I already used **JSON.stringify(test**) but it's give me o/p like : **"[Object Object]"**

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = { fields :
          {name:true, image:true, subname:false, date:true};
        }
      };
 $cookies.putObject('cookieName', obj);

/// Allows you to get the cookie back like this:

var cookieWObject = $cookies.getObject('cookieName');

/// Then get to the values like this:

var username = cookieWObject.fields.name;
var image = cookieWObject.fields.image;
```